# Disaggregate daily time series into hourly values using R

Tags: r, time-series, dataset

I'm working with a dataset that contains daily data of water flow. The data goes from 1-10-1998 to 30-03-2020 and looks like this:

```
Date        QA
1998-10-01  315
1998-10-02  245
1998-10-03  179
1998-10-04  186
1998-10-05  262
1998-10-06  199
1998-10-07  319
(...)
```

The class(Date) is "Date" and the class(QA) is "numeric".

My goal is to turn this daily data into hourly data. For this I used the function 'td' from the package 'tempdisagg' of R:

```
library(tempdisagg)
td(QA~1,to="hour",method="denton-cholette")
```

My problem is in the definition of QA as a time series variable. When I define it as 'ts' and apply the function to disaggregate the data, the following error appears:

```
QA_ts <- ts(QA, start = decimal_date(as.Date("1998-10-01")), frequency = 365)
td(QA_ts ~ 1, to = "hour",method="denton-cholette")

Error in td(QA_ts ~ 1, to = "hour",method="denton-cholette") : 
  use a time series class other than 'ts' to deal with 'hour'
```

And when I define QA as another format such as "xts" or "msts" I get the following error:

```
newQA <- xts(QA,Date)
td(newQA ~1, to="hour",method="denton-cholette")

Error in seq.Date(lf[1], lf.end, by = to) : 'to' must be a "Date" object
```

I think I'm doing something wrong when defining QA as time series but I can't solve this issue.

Can anybody help me out?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`Date` needs to be of class `POSIXct`, rather than `Date`, to convert to hourly frequency. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
x <- structure(list(time = structure(c(10227, 10258, 10286, 10317, 
10347, 10378, 10408), class = "Date"), value = c(315, 245, 179, 
186, 262, 199, 319)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Disaggratate to days:

```r
library(tempdisagg)
m0 <- td(x ~ 1, to = "day", method = "fast")
#> Loading required namespace: tsbox
predict(m0)
#> # A tibble: 212 x 2
#>    time       value
#>    <date>     <dbl>
#>  1 1998-01-01  10.4
#>  2 1998-01-02  10.3
#>  3 1998-01-03  10.3
#>  4 1998-01-04  10.3
#>  5 1998-01-05  10.3
#>  6 1998-01-06  10.3
#>  7 1998-01-07  10.3
#>  8 1998-01-08  10.3
#>  9 1998-01-09  10.3
#> 10 1998-01-10  10.3
#> # … with 202 more rows
```

If you want to disaggregate to hours, time need to be POSIXct:

```r
x$time <- as.POSIXct(x$time)
m1 <- td(x ~ 1, to = "hour", method = "fast")
predict(m1)
#> # A tibble: 5,087 x 2
#>    time                value
#>    <dttm>              <dbl>
#>  1 1998-01-01 01:00:00 0.431
#>  2 1998-01-01 02:00:00 0.431
#>  3 1998-01-01 03:00:00 0.431
#>  4 1998-01-01 04:00:00 0.431
#>  5 1998-01-01 05:00:00 0.431
#>  6 1998-01-01 06:00:00 0.431
#>  7 1998-01-01 07:00:00 0.431
#>  8 1998-01-01 08:00:00 0.431
#>  9 1998-01-01 09:00:00 0.431
#> 10 1998-01-01 10:00:00 0.431
#> # … with 5,077 more rows
```

[Here](https://github.com/christophsax/tempdisagg/issues/39) is a slightly more complex example for hourly disaggregation.

This [post](https://www.cynkra.com/blog/2020-02-09-tempdisagg/) explains conversion to high-frequency in more detail.